# How to receive RANGE data from BeatPicker by POST PHP method?

Tags: javascript, php, post, datepicker

I like to use BeatPicker (http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/demos.html ) but don’t know how to receive data if use ranges ( 2 separate input with date picker ).
If I add "name" to input then receive only first date.

```
<input type="text"
    name="FirstDate"      
    data-beatpicker="true"                
    data-beatpicker-position="['*','*']"                
    data-beatpicker-range="true"
/>
```

Comment: I think You need to put two different name for two different input field.

Comment: But there is no 2 separate input fields. Only one and if i add this option: 'data-beatpicker-range="true"' then automaticly shows 2 separate inputs

Answer (score 0):

markup:

```
<input type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-id="test" data-beatpicker-position="['*','*']" data-beatpicker-range="true"/>
```

javascript:

```
test.getSelectedEndDate()
```

from:

http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/#comment-1643118746